# Data access framework for delphi

Tags: delphi, code-generation, data-access-layer

Is there any framework or code generator for data access in Delphi based on layered architecture?

Comment: I think they usually call it "Multitier architecture", not "layered".

Comment: I want create software with 3 layers: DAL, BLL and UI. What this called?

Comment: put that in your question, because it's not "Layered Architecture". In fact the first hit when Googling for "layered architecture" is Wikipedia's page on "Multitire architecture", hence the confusion and the two answers you got on **Multitire!**

Comment: 3-Tier = 3-Layer, more or less: ["the concepts of layer and tier are often used interchangeably. However, one fairly common point of view is that there is indeed a difference, and that a layer is a logical structuring mechanism for the elements that make up your software solution, while a tier is a physical structuring mechanism for the system infrastructure."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilayered_architecture) But from the Delphi POV, Multi-Tier and Layers are the same, most of the time. You can separate physical layers into multi-tiers or not.

Comment: please ask a different question on separating business layer from presentation layer from data access layer, because this question was answered in it's asked form and changing it now would not be fare to those that put effort into answering it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Delphi has already Multi-Tier / Layered architecture available since early versions. You were never limited to RAD components.

DataSnap is certainly the de-facto standard version of building such applications. See [e.g. this article from Embarcadero](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/40668).

Other [Service-Based frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231824/client-server-application-writing-in-delphi) written on Delphi are available (DataAbstract,
RemObjects, KBMMw, Midware, WST, Synopse, Spring).

[ORM framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422426/orm-for-delphi-win32) are a good way of creating multi-tier separated applications (e.g. InstantObjects, DObject, tiOPF, GFramewok, Bold, Synopse, hcOPF, DelphiORM..). Some of them even allow to build Services above ORM. See for instance our [Open source framework](http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=93).

Comment: +1 because it answer the asked question. Not the question the OP intended, but that's the OP's fault!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the various Object Persistence Frameworks out on the market. We have been using [tiOPF](http://tiopf.sourceforge.net/) for some years and are very happy with it. Although it has a very steep learning curve.

There are others available as well, like [hcOPF](http://www.tpersistent.com/)